# Scala Play parse json stream (ndjson)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have an endpoint that produces `application/stream+json` or `application/x-ndjson` (http://ndjson.org/).

I'm trying to consume this endpoint with Play. Specifically I've used `WSResponse.json` but it only seem to parse the first item returned. I also tried `WSResponse.validate[Seq[JsValue]]` but it fails with `JsonValidationError`.

Is it possible to parse this output with Play and get a `Seq` or even a `Source` (akka-streams)?

Comment: First use akka-stream framing to split the message, then parse each message. Check whether something is not yet provided for, e.g in alpakka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed create a solution based on cchantep's comment

Using [akka-streams framing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html#using-framing-in-your-protocol), specifically the class `JsonFraming` will do the trick. I ended up with something like this:

```scala
// declaration or injection of WSClient

ws.url(url)
  .post(body)
  .flatMap { response =>
    for {
      jsonStrs <- response.bodyAsSource.via(JsonFraming.objectScanner(Int.MaxValue))
        .runFold(Seq.empty[String]) {
          case (acc, entry) => acc ++ Seq(entry.utf8String)
        }
    } yield {
      jsons.map(Json.parse)
    }
  }
```

The code above will produce a `Future[Seq[JsValue]]` which can be manipulated as needed.